# Intersect split string with partial words on list (possibly with regex)

Tags: python, string, list

I have two lists:

```
keywords = ['critic', 'argu', 'dog', 'cat']
splitSentences = ['Add', 'critical', 'argument', 'birds']
```

I need to find how many words in `splitSentence` begin with words of `keywords`. In my example, that would be `2` (for *critical* matching "critic" and *argument* matching "argu").

The problem is that doing `set(keywords).intersection(splitSentences)` returns `0`. I tried prefixing every word in `keywords` with `^`, but it still returns 0.

Apologies, quite new on Python. I'm working on a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex:

```
import re

for i in keywords:
    count = 0
    pref = '^'+ i
    for word in splitSentences:
        if re.match(pref, word):
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

The semi one liner:

```
for i in keywords:
    print(sum([1 for word in splitSentences if word.startswith(i)]))
```

The one liner:

```
print({el:sum([1 for word in splitSentences if word.startswith(el)]) for el in keywords})
```

Comment: Your one-liner isn’t actually a one-liner. This would be it:  `sum([1 for k in keywords for s in splitSentences if s.startswith(k)])` or `len([s for k in keywords for s in splitSentences if s.startswith(k)])`

Comment: The `len` modification worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Why not join all the prefixes into a single regex, then let the regex library do the heavy lifting?